# Deserialize non-standard XML file with C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML without success.

**XML input file:**

```
<PERSONS>
  <INFO1>No Errors</INFO1><INFO2>Group 12</INFO2><INFO3>TX</INFO3><INFO4>US77002</INFO4>
<PERSON>
 <E1>1972/01/21</E1><E2>08:00:12</E2><E8>Jimmy</E8><E10>Smith</E10><E9>4120120212</E9>
 <E6><T1>201</T1><T2>Good</T2><T3>1234</T3></E6> <E7><T1>202</T1><T2>Very good</T2><T3>4124</T3></E7> </PERSON>
<PERSON>
 <E1>1972/01/21</E1><E2>08:00:12</E2><E8>Jimmy</E8><E10>Smith</E10><E9>4120120212</E9>
 <E6><T1>201</T1><T2>Good</T2><T3>1234</T3></E6> <E7><T1>202</T1><T2>Very good</T2><T3>4124</T3></E7> </PERSON>
...
</PERSONS>
```

I want to retrieve all data of each Person and also the T1, T2 etc. within E6 and E7.
How can I accomplish that?

I tried to deserialize with the XmlSerializer but getting InvalidOperation Exception.

**Code snippet:**

```
    private static PersonCollection GetPersonCollection()
    {
        PersonCollection persons = null;
        string path = "personfile.xml";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonCollection));

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        persons = (PersonCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();

        return persons;
    }


[Serializable()]
public class PersonCollection
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("E1")]
    public string E1 { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("E2")]
    public string E2 { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("E3")]
    public string E3 { get; set; }

... // XmlAttribute for T1, T2, T3 ??
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps not relevant for your situation, but in my experience it's best to start out with creating a dummy object in your program with standard C# code, and then serialize the object, so then you can see what the XML should look like.

Comment: From http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp it looks like valid XML, so I'm not sure what's meant by "non-standard"

Comment: @TimS.: It does seem to be missing the outermost element less-than question-mark xml version="1.0" encoding= etc.